# Finding intersection of two querysets of two different models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My models.py looks something like

```
class RelevanceRelation(TimeStampable, SoftDeletable, models.Model):
    relevance_type = models.ForeignKey(
        RelevanceType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="relevance_relations"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,
                            verbose_name="Relevance Relation Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RelevanceRelationValue(TimeStampable, SoftDeletable, models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(
        Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="relevance_relation_values"
    )
    relevance_relation = models.ForeignKey(
        RelevanceRelation,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="values"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,
                             verbose_name="Relevance Relation Value")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I have two querysets

```
q1 = RelevanceRelationValue.objects.filter(entity=<int>)
q2 = RelevanceRelation.objects.filter(relevance_type=<int>)
```

Now is there a way to find intersection of `q1` and `q2` i.e I wan't to display all the values of `q2` whose `id` is present in `q1 as rulevance_relation`

For example:

```
q1 = -------------------------------
     | entity | relevance_relation |
     -------------------------------
     |   1    |        1           |
     |   1    |        2           |
     |   1    |        3           |
     -------------------------------

and q2 = -------------------------------
         |   id.  | relevance_type     |
         -------------------------------
         |   1    |        1           |
         |   2    |        1           |
         |   3    |        1           |
         |   4    |        1           |
         |   5    |        1           |
         |   6    |        1           |
         ------------------------------- 

so q3 should be 
         -------------------------------
         |   id.  | relevance_type     |
         -------------------------------
         |   1    |        1           |
         |   2    |        1           |
         |   3    |        1           |
         -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform extra filtering:

```
q1 = RelevanceRelationValue.objects.filter(entity=some_value1).values('relevance_relation')
q2 = RelevanceRelation.objects.filter(
    relevance_type=some_value2,
    id__in=q1
)
```

But it makes more sense to simply filter on the related model, so:

```
RelevanceRelation.objects.filter(
    values__entity=some_value1,
    relevance_type=some_value2
).distinct()
```

Here we thus get all `RelevanceRelation`s for which the `relevance_type` is `some_value2`, and for which a *related* `RelevanceRelationValue` exists with `entity=some_value1`.

Comment: I am getting an error ```Original exception text was: 'RelevanceRelation' object has no attribute 'entity_type'.```

Comment: @Jack: well that is correct, a `RelevanceRelation` has indeed no attriubte `.entity_type`, so likely further in you code you aim to obtain attributes that do not exist for the given model.

Comment: oh yes I was calling wrong serialiser and Thank You for the help